# Android Activity calling itself

Tags: android

Suppose I have an Android `Activity` and I have a variable `count` associated with it.

I call the `Activity` itself and send `count+5` in `putExtra()`

Now I want the previous `Activities` to retain retain their `count` values.

How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try it? If yes, show the code and tell us what happened.

Comment: You could use SharedPreferences to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Not clearly understand what you want to do exactly. Is that the behavior you want?

Specify the activity's launch mode as default and standard. Every time you start this activity, a new instance of that activity will be created and put to back stack. Every activity instance has the member "count" will retained it's value unless you modify the value manually.

Answer (score 0):

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener{

```
public  ListView lv;
public ArrayList<String> items=new ArrayList<String>();
public static int flag=0;
public int Hello=0;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    items.add("123"); items.add("234");
    if(flag>0) {
        Intent i=getIntent();
        int pos=i.getExtras().getInt("shared");
        items.add(pos+"");
    }
    lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items));

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
    flag++;
    ++Hello;
    intent.putExtra("shared",Hello);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Now whenever I start an activity within an activity it takes value of Hello as 0 and increments it and I always put 1 in putExtra but whenever I go back to the previous activity(closing the current activity) and again I open an acitivity it takes Hello as 1 and appends 2 to the new window and so i.e

Acticity 1: LListeView (123,234)

I open an acticity in Activity 1 and in Acticity 2 I have ListView(123,234,1)

I open an acticity in Activity 2 and in Acticity 3 I have ListView(123,234,1)

I close Activity 3 and again I open an acticity in Acticity 2 but this time Listview of 
Acticity 3 is(123,234,2)

I don't understand why Hello gets to 2 in the end

Instead of this I want

Activity 1 ListView:(123,234)

I open an acticity in Activity 1 and in Acticity 2 I should have ListView(123,234,1)

I open an acticity in Activity 2 and in Acticity 3 I should have ListView(123,234,2)

I close Activity 3 and again I open an acticity in Activity 2 and Activity 3 should have

ListView as (123,234,2) i.e. the value of Hello corresponding to the Activities should remain constant